Why IIS returning 403 forbidden when upload some file ? many of then success but there are failed
I have an API using .NET Framework 4.8. Deployed on IIS 10. Hosted in AWS EC2 with ELB.
All the endpoint is works as expected, including the get file endpoint. But I Have one endpoint for uploading file. For many files, it works. But user have a file that returning 403 forbidden error when he upload that file.
So, I ask user the file that causing error. I run the API on my local machine, then try to upload that file, and no error.
I guess the problem is in IIS, the server or AWS.
Here is the log in inetpub/log/logfiles

I try to save as the file using paint. Try to upload on production server and it works.
This is frustrating the user because they have to save as the file using paint before uploading the file.
Any suggestion guys?
I want user does not have to save as the file before upload the file.

Why don't you show the log entries for those 403 in the question?

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

@LexLi no entries found for 403 error in inetpub/log/logfiles

@samwu I have tried to enable/generate FRT, but no configure > Failed Request Tracing is action pane, I am looking for how to enable FRT, but do not find how to do it in IIS 10

You can refer to this link: Enable Failed Request Tracing.

I found the solution.
Just add X-XSS-Protection=1 to the request header.
Thanks
